# How to pass object to partial in dot.js

Tags: javascript, template-engine, dot.js

I am trying to pass a new created object to my dot.js partial snippet like this :

```js
try {
  var tempFn = doT.template($('#myTpl').text());
  var resultText = tempFn({
    "foo": "this snippet"
  });
  $('#result').html(resultText);
} catch (e) {
  $('#error').show().html(e);
  throw e;
}
```

```css
#error {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dot/1.0.3/doT.js"></script>

<!-- Template HERE -->
<script id="myTpl" type="template/doT.js">//<![CDATA[
{{##def.snippet:obj:
  <div>How to use {{=obj.x}}</div>
#}} 
{{#def.snippet:{"x":it.foo}}}
// ]]></script>


<div id="result"></div>
<div id="error" style="display: none;"></div>
```

But I get `Template has an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`
So how can I create and pass object (or multiple params) to a defined partial ?

What's going wrong ?

**EDIT:**

I have a schedule structure that come from a REST webservice like that :

```
"schedule": {
      "MONDAY": {
        "amOpenTime": {
          "hours": 8,
          "minutes": 30
        },
        "amCloseTime": null,
        "pmOpenTime": null,
        "pmCloseTime": {
          "hours": 17,
          "minutes": 0
        }
      },
      "TUESDAY": {
        "amOpenTime": {
          "hours": 8,
          "minutes": 31
        },
        "amCloseTime": null,
        "pmOpenTime": null,
        "pmCloseTime": {
          "hours": 17,
          "minutes": 40
        }
      },
      ....
}
```

I would to do not repeat my templating for each day because they must be processed in same way (DRY!)
So I consider using partial snippet to print each line of my schedule (morning open/close time and afternoon open/close time).
So as morning and afternoon div sould be threated in same way, I would like to create a second snippet to handle that. But for morning I need to pass only *am* prefixed data and *pm* prefixed data for afternoon like that :

```
{{##def.scheduleHalfDay:fday:
// multiple condition that I ommited
<div class="closed {{fday.type}}">{{fday.openTime.hours}}:{{fday.openTime.minutes}} - {{fday.closeTime.hours}}:{{fday.closeTime.minutes}}</div>
#}}

{{##def.scheduleRow:hday:
{{? (typeof hday.amOpenTime === "undefined" || hday.amOpenTime === null) && (typeof hday.pmCloseTime === "undefined" || hday.pmCloseTime == null) }}
<div class="closed">Closed</div>
{{??}}
{{#def.scheduleHalfDay:{"type": "morning", "openTime": hday.amOpenTime, "closeTime": hday.amCloseTime}}}--{{#def.scheduleHalfDay:{"type": "afternoon", "openTime": hday.pmOpenTime, "closeTime": hday.pmCloseTime}}}
{{?}}
#}}
<div class="agency-schedules">
    <div class="line"><div class="agency-schedules-day">Monday</div>{{#def.scheduleRow:it.horaires.MONDAY}}</div>
    <div class="line"><div class="agency-schedules-day">Tuesday</div>{{#def.scheduleRow:it.horaires.TUESDAY}}</div>
    ...
</div>
```

scheduleHalfDay are not working. So how can I pass my 3 parameters properly (without change data structure) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to make it work is to declare your param as a variable.

`{{ var param = {"x":it.foo}; }}
{{#def.snippet:param}}`

Answer (score 0):

First, your template has HTML in it so you should use `.html()` to get the template text.

Second, brackets, { and }, are reserved for doT template borders so you can't have them in templates.

Third, you don't need to use a partial there if all you're doing is passing an object to a template:

```
<script id="myTpl" type="template/doT.js">
  {{##def.snippet:
    <div>How to use {{=it.foo}}</div>
  #}}
  {{#def.snippet}}
</script>
```

Here's the simple working example: https://jsfiddle.net/silkster/wq5tjzrt/

Here's an example of transforming your position data and passing it to doT: https://jsfiddle.net/silkster/wq5tjzrt/2/

**EDIT**

From the new data you added, it seems what you need is an array of days. What you have in the original JSON data is a regular object with day names as properties. In my 3rd example below, I transform the object into an array of days and pass that to doT to output a schedule and use a partial template to show the opening and closing times for each day.

One edit I had to do in the partial template was to change the snippet so the correct properties are used in the template.

**This might be the answer you're looking for:** 
When you define the partial template, use the variable that will be available when the partial is used. "it" is the default, but if you use the partial in a loop as in my example, then define the partial with the variable as defined within the loop template.

Also, while transforming the data, add any data from calculations that you might need in your template. For example, if you need to determine if the opening time and closing time happen in am or pm, then do that while transforming the data and add the new key/value pairs to the transformed data.

Example 3 using your schedule data: https://jsfiddle.net/silkster/nq6guog9/

Comment: FYI - in the exmaple, I changed the template script tag to <div> since script isn't allowed in HTML blocks on jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes. I know how simple template are working. I just made a simple example to explain the problem ! For exemple I get a json fro webservice(that I can't change structure) : `{ "pos1": {"topX": 1, "topY": 2, "leftX": 10, "leftY": 20 }, "pos2": .... }` and I want to only pass to my snippet pos1 top value first and after left value like that: `{ "pos": {"x": it.pos1.topX, "y": it.pos1.topY }}` and my template could be : `<div>x={{=pos.x}}, y={{=pos.y}}</div>`. How do you perform that (I want to understand partials !!) ?

Comment: Partials work the same as a regular template. I updated the same jsfiddle with a partial template. https://jsfiddle.net/silkster/wq5tjzrt/

Comment: So how to pass object or multiples parameters to partial ? (jsfiddle haven't changed)

Comment: You need to transform your data to match what you expect (or want) in the template. You could also just pass the raw data into the template and use {{=it.pos1.topX}} {{=it.pos1.leftX}}. I added a 2nd link to jsFiddle so you can see more updates with your data.

Comment: Basically, the template doesn't do any logic, it just accepts data and displays it. You need to do any transformations before calling the template function.

Comment: Basically, my question is not about data structure but how to create sub object or **multiple parameters** in partial (that all).

Comment: I add my real example to better understanding in question